# Transfer from web site asp.net to android and from android to web site aps.net?

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net

How can I transfer data from website asp.net to android application and mobile to web site.
EX: I want transfer mark each student from web site to device student in application.
please: give me Example or tutorial about that and what is technical use?

Comment: You don't transfer data from the website to android. The android app can read the data from the website. Like @LukeHutton said, write yourself an API, or use something like [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) or [ASP.NET Web Wervices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx)

Comment: if change in data in android,i want transfer data to website for update data base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Web Services for server side and [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) for client side android application.

In this way you can send data to your website or update your database by calling web services (web methods).

Here is a nice tutorial on how to use ksoap2: http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/03/03/how-to-consume-web-services-from-android-applications-using-ksoap2/

And a tutorial for how to create .NET Web Service: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service